# Error: No component factory found for TermsConditions

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

I am getting this Error:

> No component factory found for TermsConditions while using angular2-rc6.

My route map is like this:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: TermsConditions
}
```

Comment: Are you exporting `TermsConditions` component?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan: Can you explain me a bit more why this is required?
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule ],
    declarations : [
        TermsConditionsComponent
    ]
})
export default class TermsConditions {}

Comment: `declarations` is for using the component within the Module, and `exports` is for using it externally. You may read more about Modules [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) and [FAQ here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html), they explain these concepts in depth.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan: Thanks but still getting the same after exporting the same.


@NgModule({
    declarations : [
        TermsConditionsComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        TermsConditionsComponent
    ]
})
export default class TermsConditions {}

Comment: can you add more, on how you are activating the Route? and more code, May be create a Plunker reproducing the issue.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer this doesn't seem like a duplicate of the Q you referenced. That one is about dynamically loaded components, where as this is straight up module configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I got to know how to fix this issue.

> No component factory found for TermsConditions.

```
  @NgModule({ 
          declarations : [ TermsConditionsComponent ]
        }) 
        export default class TermsConditions {}
```

1. Import this module to your root module.

   ```
      @NgModule({ 
         declarations : [ AppComponent ],
         imports: [ BrowserModule, TermsConditions ],
         bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
       }) 
       export default class AppModule {}
   ```
2. use component in routing like.

   ```
   { 
     path : 'terms',
     component : TermsConditionsComponent
   }
   `
   ```

It means your module is not available in application scope that is why your component is not being bind to router.

Answer (score 2):

You need to list the TermsConditions in both the `declarations` and `entryComponents` section.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39376857

Comment: entryComponents is used for root level app not for the child level app.

Comment: entryComponents is used for listing the components which does not have any reference in templates in any component tree.