# Nativescript custom dialog exception

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to get a custom dialog modal popup in nativescript (angular 2) by following [this example](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/dialogs#custom-dialog).

Any idea why when clicking the SHOW button I get the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION: No component factory found for DialogContent (d:\npn\qwe\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:3462:27)
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: (d:\npn\qwe\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:3467:31)
Error: No component factory found for DialogContent
    at NoComponentFactoryError.Error (native)
    at NoComponentFactoryError.BaseError [as constructor] (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1255:38)
    at new NoComponentFactoryError (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6053:20)
    at _NullComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6062:19)
    at NgModuleInjector.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6087:39)
    at DetachedLoader.loadInLocation (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/common/detached-loader.js:18:37)
    at DetachedLoader.loadComponent (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/common/detached-loader.js:30:21)
    at ModalDialogService.showDialog (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs.js:51:36)
    at /data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs.js:27:51
  at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.qwe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:223:37) (d:\npn\qwe\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:3468:31)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in [another so.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373991/angular2-rc-5-no-component-factory-found-for-dynamically-loaded-components) In the main module you have to add:

```
@NgModule({
   ....
    declarations: [ DialogContent ],
    entryComponents: [ DialogContent ]
})
```

Comment: good man, also make sure you've got this import `import { DialogContent } from './components/app/dialogcontent` in your `app.module.ts` file