# Add / update routes in Angular Lazy loading module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have been trying to alter lazy loading routes in Angular at runtime.

I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45112) but they asked me to create a question here.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: SetupComponent },
    { path: 'usermanagement', loadChildren: () => import('./usermanagement/usermanagement.module').then(m => m.UsermanagementModule) },
    { path: 'organization', loadChildren: () => import('./organization/organization.module').then(m => m.OrganizationModule) },
];
```

User management routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('./users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule) },
    { path: 'roles', loadChildren: () => import('./roles/roles.module').then(m => m.RolesModule) },
];
```

User routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: UsersComponent },
    { path: 'new', component: UserNewComponent },
    { path: 'edit/:id', component: UserEditComponent }
];
```

At the application start, I would like to inject a route `/usermanagement/users/xxxxx` in the Users Module or change the component associated with the `/users/new` route.

```js
{ path: 'xxxxx', component: DynamicComponent }
```

I did try  the following, but it is always loading original routes:

```js
if (parentRoute.loadChildren) {
    await(<any>this.router).configLoader.load(this.injector, parentRoute).subscribe({
        next: (moduleConf: any) => {
            let routestoUpdate: Routes = moduleConf.routes;
            if (`${routeToAdd}` === "") {
                routestoUpdate = this.removeExistingRoutes(routestoUpdate, "");
                routestoUpdate = this.removeExistingRoutes(routestoUpdate, "new");
                routestoUpdate = this.removeExistingRoutes(routestoUpdate, "edit/:id");
            } else {
                routestoUpdate = this.removeExistingRoutes(routestoUpdate, `${routeToAdd}`);
                routestoUpdate = this.removeExistingRoutes(routestoUpdate, `${routeToAdd}/new`);
                routestoUpdate = this.removeExistingRoutes(routestoUpdate, `${routeToAdd}/edit/:id`);
            }
            routestoUpdate.push(
                {
                    path: `${routeToAdd}`,
                    component: BeholderHomeComponent,
                    data: { breadcrumb: customRoute.display_name, link: false, page_id: customRoute.page_id }
                },
                {
                    path: `${routeToAdd}` === "" ? "new" : `${routeToAdd}/new`,
                    component: BeholderNewComponent,
                    data: { breadcrumb: 'BUTTON.NEW', link: false, page_id: customRoute.page_id }
                },
                {
                    path: `${routeToAdd}` === "" ? "edit/:id" : `${routeToAdd}/edit/:id`,
                    component: BeholderEditComponent,
                    data: { breadcrumb: 'BUTTON.EDIT', link: false, page_id: customRoute.page_id }
                }
            );
            ** WHAT IS RIGHT WAY TO UPDATE USERS ROUTES**
            moduleConf.routes = [...routestoUpdate];
            // moduleConf.routes = routestoUpdate;
            //  moduleConf.module.injector.get(Router).resetConfig(routestoUpdate);
            setTimeout(async () => {
                await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(moduleConf.module.injector.instance);
                this.router.config.unshift(...routestoUpdate);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I dynamically change routes at runtime?

Comment: Apparently you can use [`Router.resetConfig`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#resetconfig) to change the routing at runtime. However, I wouldn't know how you should deal with lazy-loading in this case... [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42928292/8941307)

Comment: [This seems to be a good article](https://mokkapps.de/blog/manually-lazy-load-modules-and-components-in-angular/) which includes lazy loading

Comment: did you got solution?